# Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue in flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter. I have got error

"loading many images goes out of memory in flutter ios"

and I got message from debugger

"Terminated due to memory issue".

I have tryout all of image view - cache_image, progress_image, extended_image but still got same error so please if you have any idea about this and solution for this so help me. Thanks in advance!!

- Screen shot of XCode console,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is due to too much memory consumption, I got same error for my project as well but it was very difficult to find it, for me I was using a

```
ListView.builder
```

with

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

which load the whole data once and occupy memory, and for long list of data, I got same error. I hope this will help to find problem for this issue